# Linq group join

Tags: c#, linq

How to write `Description` from `Recipe` in `recipe=`.
I tried to use `join r in Recipe on d.DishID equals r.DishID` but it giving wrong result. It erase one item in result1.

Exptected output:

[image]

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Component> Component = new List<Component>();
            List<Dish> Dish = new List<Dish>();
            List<Recipe> Recipe = new List<Recipe>();
            Dish.Add(new Dish { DishID = 9, CategoryID = 6, DishName = "Pork" });
            Dish.Add(new Dish { DishID = 10, CategoryID = 6, DishName = "Beef" });
            Component.Add(new Component { ComponentID = 1, DishID = 9, AmountID = "1", NameID = "1" });
            Recipe.Add(new Recipe { DishID = 9, RecipeID = 0, Description = "Test" });

            var result1 = (
            from d in Dish
            //join r in Recipe on d.DishID equals r.DishID 
            join c in Component on d.DishID equals c.DishID into items
            select new Item { DishID = d.DishID, components = items.ToList() recipe=}
            ).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public int DishID { get; set; }

        public string DishName { get; set; }

        public string recipe { get; set; }

        public List<Component> components { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Component
    {
        public int ComponentID { get; set; }
        public int DishID { get; set; }
        public string AmountID { get; set; }
        public string NameID { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Dish
    {
        public int DishID { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string DishName { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class Recipe
    {
        public int RecipeID { get; set; }
        public int DishID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `but it giving wrong result.`  What is it? Sample input? expected output?

Comment: Correct your code so it runs, right now it doesn't from what you were saying gave an answer on how to do a left join in linq, but your code doesn't compile, show the code that is currently working

Comment: Is the relationship from Dish => Recipe 1 to 1? Your edit made me confused

Comment: @konkked,Yes i see confusing thing.

Comment: Made modifications to answer, uses slightly less code and to answer your question so you can remove the answer part you put in your question, pretty sure isn't supposed to be in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You want to do a left join**

To do this you need to do some extra stuff in linq, not sure why it isnt support natively but it isnt.

```
        var result1 = (
        from d in Dish
        join c in Component on d.DishID equals c.DishID into items
        join r in Recipe on d.DishID equals r.DishID into recipes
        select new Item { 

                     DishID = d.DishID, 

                     components = items.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                       .Where(a=>a!=null)
                                       .ToArray(), 

                     recipe = recipes.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    .Where(a=>a!=null)
                                    .Select(a=>a.Description)
                                    .FirstOrDefault() 
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: You should add `from r in recipes.DefaultIfEmpty()` to flatten the recipes again. Then `recipe = r?.Description`.

Comment: @GertArnold Usually answer in C#5 unless I am sure that the person can use C#6

Comment: Sure, go ahead, just indicating the right (imo) direction.